# Weird warning when reading line in C

Tags: c, centos

I read the man page of the readline function in CentOs:

> readline  returns  the  text  of  the line read.  A blank line returns
>   the empty
>          string.  If EOF is encountered while reading a line, and the line is empty, NULL
>          is  returned.   If an EOF is read with a non-empty line, it is treated as a new-
>          line.

However, when i use this command

```
if (readline(1) == NULL) return EOF;
```

I got the warning message:

> warning: comparison between pointer and integer

Anyone know how to get rid of this warning ?

Comment: Maybe the required headers which have the declaration for `readline` are not included in the source file due to which the compiler treats `readline` as a function which returns `int` and thus the warning saying comparison b/w pointer & integer

Comment: Mr Lister and another.anon.coward: You are gods :D. Other: Sorry because of this stupid question bothering you guys

Answer (score 0):

Do not waste the return of your readline :

```
char *line;
//...
line = readline(1);
if (!line)
  return EOF;
//... use line ...
```

And do not forget to #include the required header.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```